# Долго срабатывает AJAX в Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Сейчас делаю проект, и при нажатии на некоторые кнопки должен срабатывать аякс. 
Пример: поставить оценку "+" статье. При нажатии на + уходит AJAX запрос, но дело в том, что в дебаггере его время 1.883 MS и колеблится вокруг него каждый раз.
И дело ни в том, что находится в action, потому что даже если в экшне будет только return true;, то запрос выполняется 1.443 MS, что как бы слишком много. Или допустим чтобы модальное окно открыть, его контент открывается тоже где то через секунду аж. Что может быть причиной этого вообще? Вот код примера выполнения аякса. Ничего лишнего вроде нет, но непонятки вообще.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/profile/like',
        data: {id: id},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(res) {

        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
```

P.S. 
Создал отдельно тестовый проект обычный, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправлялся аякс запрос, и он отправляется идеально. Сразу же срабатывает всё. А в проекте с Yii2 именно какой то косяк

Controller:

```
public function actionUnlike() {
    $photo = Photo::findOne(Yii::$app->request->post()); // Находим фотку с этим ID (а то передадут через бурп какой то левый айдишник еще..)
    if($photo) Like::unlike(Yii::$app->request->post('id')); // принимает post ID фотки из AJAX (main.js)
 }
```

Статический метод unlike в модели:

```
  public static function unlike($id) {
    $like = Like::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'photo_id' => $id])->one();
    return $like->delete();
}
```

Внутренность обработчика в JS

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/profile/unlike',
        data: {id: id},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(res) {

        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
    }
```

Дебаггер показывает, что Unlike срабатывает примерно 1,377 ms.

Comment: дело точно не в фреймворке, покажите пожалуйста больше кода: контроллер и полный код обработчика события jQuery

Comment: Я добавил, буду рад, если поможете и найдете что-то, что является проблемным

Comment: `$photo = Photo::findOne(Yii::$app->request->post());` - а зачем вы передаёте в метод все post данные?

Comment: сервер локальный или нет? время отклика сервера проверяли?

Comment: В первом пофиксил, и передал только id из POST, спасибо. А второй случай, да, сервер локальный. А дальше вопрос нубский, но самый глупый вопрос - не заданный таки. Как проверить на локали время отклика сервера?

Comment: Но и как я говорил, даже если в action будет только return true, и я передам аяксом какие то данные ему, то все равно запрос будет овер ~1,000 MS

Comment: точно также как и не на локали `ping localsite.loc`

Comment: @Blacknife Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128 Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 0мсек, Максимальное = 0 мсек, Среднее = 0 мсек